# Python 2 vs Python 3 - Encoding

Tags: python, encoding, python-2.x

I have a simple code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text = "12É45678"
print(len(text))
```

See the Upper E with accent

Then
when I run from **python 2**, the result is 9
when I run from **python 3**, the result is 8

How to obtain 8 in python 2 (native)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `str` is a naive sequence of bytes (what we call `bytes` in Python 3). To interpret arbitrary bytes as unicode codepoints, you need to [decode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) them into a [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) object:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text = "12É45678"
print(len(text))
print(len(text.decode("utf-8")))
```

In Python 2, this prints

```
9
8
```

See also the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) from the Python 2 documentation.